# I get an error while creating a instance of the Font class in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The following line:

`my_font = tk.font.Font(size=20)`

Gives me the following error:

module `tkinter` has no attribute `font`

How to fix this.

Comment: Did you explicitly import `tkinter.font`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font` is imported separately from the main `tkinter`

This should work for you

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font
```

Then you can do this

```
root = tk.Tk()
my_font = Font(root, size=20)
```

Comment: RuntimeError: Too early to use font: no default root window

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yeah, it goes without saying that you can't run this code on its own. I've edited it to include a `root` instance of `Tk` - I assume that's clearer

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
import tkinter.font as tkFont
 
myFont = tkFont.Font(root, size=20)
```